# Bootstrap: navbar-fixed-top creates dropdowns that aren't scrollable when exceeding height of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem on my website [wetterquelle.de](http://wetterquelle.de/models):

I am using bootstrap and following code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

If one wants to get to the last item in f.e. "Europe" and the vertical height of the screen isn't big enough, there is no way to click on it because it's not scrollable. I saw ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)) that navbar-static-top avoids that problem, but that is not what I want. I still want it fixed to the top.

Comment: You want to be on the top  all navs on the same row?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restrict the height of the div containing the problem and give it `overflow:scroll:`
Do this in a `@media-query` with `min-height` so it will only show scroll on those devices.

Comment: By the way, nice site!

Comment: I added this to my css-file, but it still doesn't work (probably my fault).

`@media screen and ( max-height: 600px ){
    .dropdown-menu{
  height:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
    }
}`

Thank you! Nice to here that you like the site!

Comment: Try `@media screen and ( max-height: 600px ){ .dropdown-menu{ max-height:200px; overflow:scroll; } }` It works!  Just tried in inspector.  Chrome lets you edit anything in the source.

Comment: Make it `overflow-y` so you only get the one scroll bar!

Comment: Yes, that's even better! Helped a lot!